# How to find R and L in a circuit when you know tau and steadystate/stationary value

Tags: control-system, homework, time-constant, steady-state

I am given the circuit below:

[image: Circuit]

I know that the equation governing the circuit is:

$$
I(t) = I_{0}e^{{\frac{{-R}}{L}t}}
$$

I also know that the time constant τ is given as:

$$
\tau = \frac{{L}}{R}
$$

Further I am given that τ at a steady state to a step respons is:

$$
\tau = 4.5~\mathrm{ms}
$$

And I am given that the steady state value to that step repons is:

$$
V_{final} = 1.16~\mathrm{V}
$$

I am asked to find L and R based on the final steady-state value and τ. How do I do that?

Comment: What's the steady-state voltage across the inductor?  Answer that and you can solve the problem.

Comment: Hi John can you elaborate on how you would find TAU knowing the steady-state voltage across the inductor. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are given tau, you are trying to find L and R.  If you can find the voltage across the resistor and the current through it you can get the resistance.  From that and tau you can find the inductance.

Comment: @karlkarlsen Is \$V_{final}=v_{\left(t=\infty\right)}\$? I'm just looking at your current equation at \$t=\infty\$ and wondering about the implications for the loop.

Comment: The "governing equation" has the final current as 0A. The voltage v(t) has the final current as 1.16/R > 0A. These two  points are inconsistent, so there is no solution. You should check the source of the problem or any assumptions that have been made,

Answer (score 2):

\$I_0\$ is the steady-state value and equals the applied voltage divided by R.

So, given that \$V_{final}\$ is 1.16 volts and this equals the initial applied voltage (for a step change), you can calculate R.

You know \$\tau\$ hence you now know L.

Comment: HI Andy - how do I know what  $$I_{0} $$ is ?

Comment: It equals the applied voltage divided by R (as said in my answer).

Comment: @karlkarlsen please note the following if we are finished with this session: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Well, notice that the input current is given by:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{I}_\text{i}\left(t\right)&=\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{\text{v}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{R}+\text{sL}}\right]_{\left(t\right)}\\
\\
&=\int\limits_0^t\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\text{v}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)\right]_{\left(\tau\right)}\cdot\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{\text{R}+\text{sL}}\right]_{\left(t-\tau\right)}\space\text{d}\tau\\
\\
&=\int\limits_0^t\text{V}_\text{i}\left(\tau\right)\cdot\frac{1}{\text{L}}\cdot\exp\left(\frac{\text{R}}{\text{L}}\cdot\left(\tau-t\right)\right)\space\text{d}\tau\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{\text{L}}\int\limits_0^t\text{V}_\text{i}\left(\tau\right)\cdot\exp\left(\frac{\text{R}}{\text{L}}\cdot\left(\tau-t\right)\right)\space\text{d}\tau
\end{split}\tag1
\end{equation}

Where \$\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\cdot\right]_{\left(t\right)}\$ is the inverse Laplace transform and I applied the convolution theorem.

Now, when \$\text{V}_\text{i}\left(\tau\right)\$ is a step function (aka a stable DC-voltage) equal to \$\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}\$ we get:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{I}_\text{i}\left(t\right)&=\frac{1}{\text{L}}\int\limits_0^t\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}\cdot\exp\left(\frac{\text{R}}{\text{L}}\cdot\left(\tau-t\right)\right)\space\text{d}\tau\\
\\
&=\frac{\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}}{\text{L}}\int\limits_0^t\exp\left(\frac{\text{R}}{\text{L}}\cdot\left(\tau-t\right)\right)\space\text{d}\tau\\
\\
&=\frac{\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}}{\text{L}}\cdot\frac{\text{L}\left(1-\exp\left(-\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}t}{\displaystyle\text{L}}\right)\right)}{\text{R}}\\
\\
&=\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}\cdot\frac{1-\exp\left(-\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}t}{\displaystyle\text{L}}\right)}{\text{R}}
\end{split}\tag2
\end{equation}

So, notice that when \$t\space\to\space\infty\$:

$$\lim_{t\space\to\space\infty}\text{I}_\text{i}\left(t\right)=\lim_{t\space\to\space\infty}\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}\cdot\frac{1-\exp\left(-\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}t}{\displaystyle\text{L}}\right)}{\text{R}}=\frac{\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}}{\text{R}}\cdot\left(1-\underbrace{\lim_{t\space\to\space\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}t}{\displaystyle\text{L}}\right)}_{=\space0}\right)=\frac{\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}}{\text{R}}\tag3$$

And when \$t=\tau=\frac{\text{L}}{\text{R}}\$:

$$\text{I}_\text{i}\left(\tau\right)=\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}\cdot\frac{1-\exp\left(-\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}}{\displaystyle\text{L}}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\text{L}}{\displaystyle\text{R}}\right)}{\text{R}}=\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}\cdot\frac{1-\exp\left(-1\right)}{\text{R}}\approx\frac{0.6321\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}}{\text{R}}\tag4$$